# GWT : Using "UIObject" in another widget's UI.xml file

Tags: java, gwt

I have defined a `UiBinder` widget called *Header* with HTML markup only in *Header.ui.xml* Hence its corresponding *Header.java* class extends `UIObject` and has `setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this))` in its constructor. This gives out an `Element` object. When appended to `RootPanel.geBodyElement()` ,  It runs fine.

**Problem is:**

I want to use it in another UiBinder widgets's declarative ui.xml ( type is `Composite` with GWT Ui elements in xml) file. When I use the header widget in xml here:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <app:Header />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

GWT gives an error:  *[ERROR] Not allowed in an HTML context Element*

Can any one help ?

Comment: An easy work around is to extend from Widget , instead of UiObject. But still don't know why UiObject does not works ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [HTMLPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html) can only wrap raw HTML or GWT Widgets.